# When I query the google datastore my response is 'not found'

Tags: oauth-2.0, nsurlconnection, google-cloud-datastore

When I query the google datastore (after authenticating from iOS) - the response from my NSURLConnection is 'Not Found'. I am expecting to see something like 'missing parameters from post', or like on this site, where it says '503 service unavailable' or something like that.

```
 https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/datastore/v1beta2/datastore.datasets.runQuery
```

The code is

```
 NSString *url = @"https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1beta2/datasets/MYDATASETID/runQuery?key=MY_API_KEY";
 NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
 {
    NSString *stringData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"response is %@", stringData);
 }];
```

Where MYDATASETID is my actual project name. And I am getting these instructions for this url from the site:

```
 https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/datasets/runQuery
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for me to get a response was to set 'POST' as the HTTP Method, for example:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullUrl]];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [req setHTTPBody:[someData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Note though that this does not fully solve my challenge because although I get a response, the response from my variable stringData is
    Login Required
And the error in NSError *connectionError is

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x8e20690 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1beta2/datasets/MY_APP_ID/runQuery?key=MY_APPS_API_KEY, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1beta2/datasets/MY_APP_ID/runQuery?key=MY_APPS_API_KEY, NSUnderlyingError=0x8d6f120 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)"}
```